# Node JS executable application framework or folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory-structure

I am building a Node js application as a standalone executable, so it is not a web application or also an API. Is there any framework available, so that it can build the executable automatically?

I have looked many frameworks, but they are webapplication's and API's. Is there any other framework I can customise to build only an executable application?

1. I know I can produce an executable using "pkg".

If "pkg" like libraries is the solution, then what is the best folder structure for Node js executable project that will have the following types of functionalites.

1. The starting point (app.js)
2. The functions that can do some operations.
3. The Data files that will be used by the functions.
4. A config file where I can enter some values, that will be loaded on run time.

After structuring how can I use pkg, to build an executable with the starting point and the functions alone. It is a CLI application.

Comment: I think [Electron](https://electronjs.org) is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: As the above comment is suggesting, are you building a CLI (Command Line Interface), or an app with a Window-based UI that's launched by clicking on an icon?

Comment: You can try reading https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-your-first-app-with-electron-41ebdb796930

Comment: Building a CLI, Is there any solutions separate?  - @rjmurt

Comment: This question just ask for the folder structure, or a framework. I have not asked for a tool or software library to solve this. But still it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `package.json` you add the [executable entry point](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) like so:

```
"bin": {
  "your-exe": "./app.js"
},
```

You can then [install locally during development by running](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):

```
npm link
```

If you were to push the package to npm, users should then be able to install it by running:

```
npm install your-package
```

Which should put `your-exe` on their path

I've never used it but it looks like `pkg` will create a standalone executable that doesn't require npm. Its [docs say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) that it can read the `bin` option from your `package.json` when you configure it.

There is no one way of doing the folder structure, but what you've already said sounds good and means you would have the following in your root directory:

```
/lib
/data
/config
app.js
package.json
```